# Center gravity in ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, android-relativelayout

Hi I have a problem with centering TextView in ScrollView. I want to center my TextViews with ids `hajs`, `textView01`, `textView02` vertically in order to be in the center of height of imageViews. It's strange because in the Android Studio design I see everything right, but when I try on device I get these TextViews in the top of the TextView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:fillViewport="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/hajs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
                android:background="#41BF17"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center|center_horizontal"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="70sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="#41BF17"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/zaoszczedziles"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="#41BF17"
                android:maxWidth="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/moneybag" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/hajs"
                android:background="#41BF17"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/dni_bez_papierosow"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="#41BF17"
                android:maxWidth="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/calendar" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ImageView01"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/hajs"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ImageView01"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="#41BF17"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="70sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: which TextView you want to place center vertically?

Comment: hajs, textView01, textView02